# getInitialLink returns with NULL value after opening the deep link

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-native-ios, firebase-dynamic-links

I am working on a react Native app, that should open a firebase dynamic link. I can create the dynamic link with firebase API, but when a open the link and I would to log weather the app was from link opened, it returns just a NULL value.

I use this method:

```
 componentWillMount() {
    firebase.links()
    .getInitialLink()
    .then((url) => {
        if (url) {
            Alert.alert("Opened from link")// app opened from a url
        } else {
          Alert.alert("Not opened linkes") // app NOT opened from a url
        }
    });
  }
```

Could someone check it please what I am making wrong?

Comment: Are you using npm firebase package i mean the normal web SDK or [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/).

Comment: I am using expo-firebase package for react-native

Comment: that is the normal web SDK. it doesnt support firebase dynamic link

Comment: As I know it react-native-firebase uses web SDK as well

Comment: It doesnt. It implements native SDK. take a look here and see which modules you can use from the firebase Web SDK on react-native. [supported-firebase-features](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase#supported-firebase-features)

Comment: Oh, thank you. I was on wrong way, now I am using react-native-firebase with the native firebase SDK, which working perfectly. Before that I had to eject to the expokit.

Comment: @RobertKovacs Are you able to get link if app is not installed and installed from store/custom link ?